# Audio recorder script works on most browsers except the Edge browser

Tags: javascript, audio, microsoft-edge

Hello I found this script that gives you the ability to record an audio file in the browser so this works on most browsers except on Edge. So on page load I get this error.

- error 0: 'MediaRecorder' is not defined

and when I press the record button then I get this error.

- 0: 'rec' is not defined

And then when I press stop then I get this error.

- 0: 'rec' is not defined

So I don't know how I can get this to work on Edge.

I try to mess with it but I still can't figure it out how and I can not find any sources online that can help me out on this one.

Here is the code

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  })
  .then(stream => {
    handlerFunction(stream)
  })

function handlerFunction(stream) {
  rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  rec.ondataavailable = e => {
    audioChunks.push(e.data);
    if (rec.state == "inactive") {
      let blob = new Blob(audioChunks, {
        type: 'audio/mpeg-3'
      });
      recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      recordedAudio.controls = true;
      recordedAudio.autoplay = true;
      sendData(blob)
    }
  }
}

function sendData(data) {}

record.onclick = e => {
  console.log('I was clicked')
  record.disabled = true;
  record.style.backgroundColor = "blue"
  stopRecord.disabled = false;
  audioChunks = [];
  rec.start();
}
stopRecord.onclick = e => {
  console.log("I was clicked")
  record.disabled = false;
  stop.disabled = true;
  record.style.backgroundColor = "red"
  rec.stop();
}
```

```css
#record {
  background-color: red;
  /* Green */
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#stopRecord {
  background-color: green;
  /* Green */
  border-width: medium;
  border-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50%;
  max-height: 15%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

h2 {
  left: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#recordedAudio {
  left: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h2>Record</h2>
<p>
  <button id=record></button>
  <button id=stopRecord disabled>Stop</button>
</p>
<p>
  <audio id=recordedAudio></audio>
</p>
```

Comment: What version of Edge are you on? it [should be supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=mediarecorder).

Comment: Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0

Comment: Hm, that should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Some versions of Edge don't support the MediaRecorder API, which is the backbone for the recording script you're using.

You can use [`audio-recorder-polyfill`](https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill) to polyfill it. You'll need to use some sort of bundler to get it in your app.

For debugging reference. The `MediaRecorder is not defined` message tells you that there's no variable called `MediaRecorder` in scope (i.e. the `window`), which means it's not already defined by the browser and is likely not a supported feature.

In the future, I'd suggest trying to understand the code you use before you use it; you're exposing yourself to many bugs without doing so.

Comment: As a side note the recording is almost always in the Opus format (MIME type `audio/ogg`) so you should not be declaring the `Blob` as type `audio/mpeg-3`.

Comment: I do try to understand it somethings take time to understand perfectly that's why I go on here so I can have a better understanding but sadly your link did not help me out at all but thanks for responding to me I really appreciate your effort to inform me but I'm still having problems with the code still.

Answer (score 0):

React supports all popular browsers, including Internet Explorer 9 and above, although some polyfills are required for older browsers such as IE 9 and IE 10.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MediaStream Recording API document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API), we can see that the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) object support Edge 79+ version, and not available to the legacy version Edge browser (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0). The Edge 79+ version browser is chromium based.

So, to use MediaRecorder object, please try to install the [new Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)(it is chromium based, and at present, the latest Edge version is Version 81.0.416.53 (Official build) (64-bit)).